# JSR223: Calling Java "varargs" methods from script

Tags: java, scripting, variadic-functions

I have a method that looks like this on Java:

```
public void myMethod(Object... parms);
```

But I can't call this method as expected from the scripts.

If, in ruby, I do:

```
$myObject.myMethod(42);
```

It gives me `org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: could not coerce Fixnum to class [Ljava.lang.Object`

If I try the following in Javascript:

```
myObject.myMethod(42);
```

Then it gives me `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Can't find method MyClass.test(number). (#2) in  at line number 2`

Of course, if I change the signature to take one single object then it works.

I assume that this is because someone along the line does not know how to convert, say `Integer` to `Integer[]` with the value at the first position.

I believe something like `myMethod({42, 2009})` would work in Ruby, but this seems ugly - I wanted to be able to just do `myMethod(42, 2009)` to make it less confusing, specially for other languages. Is there any better workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Java internally treats the variable-length argument list as an array whose elements are all of the same type. That is the reason why you need to provide an array of objects in your JRuby script.

It works like this:

```
myMethod [42, 2009].to_java
```

The `to_java` method constructs a Java array from a Ruby array. By default, `to_java` constructs Object arrays as needed in this case. If you need a String array you would use

```
["a","b","c"].to_java(:string)
```

More on this at the [JRuby wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/CallingJavaFromJRuby#Arrays)

Comment: another example: 
jruby -rjava -e 'fmt = java.util.Formatter.new(); puts fmt.format("|%4s|", ["üü"].to_java)'

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is a known bug in jruby. See [method dispatch on Java objects / classes should try to find a matching varargs method](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-195) and [NameError thrown when trying to pass argument to a Java method that is defined as having variable length arguments](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-1924).

According to the link Rhino does [support vararg](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382457).

Answer (score 0):

Varargs are handled by the compiler as an Object[] which is what the error message describes.

I do not have JRuby experience, but does it work if you have an array argument?